# how to control the joints of my infant 3d model in unity with ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have an 3d model of rigged infant model which I can able to control in unity with c#. I would like to know how to publish a numerical value on ROS and read this value on Unity and use it to control the infant model?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392831/how-to-control-the-joints-of-my-infant-3d-model-in-unity-with-ros?/) by [kamali](https://answers.ros.org/users/91584/kamali/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2021-12-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, you can use ros sharp https://github.com/siemens/ros-sharp
it allow you to use ros with c sharp. and unity is also supported

for introduction you can the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sup2Tdxt1ko

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2021-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1